# Включение административной защиты WAS

Tags: linux

Пытаюсь включить административную защиту в Websphere Application Server. В качестве хранилища учетных записей указываю значение Локальная операционная система. Провернуть все это дело пытаюсь на linux mint. В итоге меня просто не пускает в консоль администратора, пароль не верный, хотя указываю от ОС. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: *пароль не верный, хотя указываю от ОС* — а учётную запись вы от *чего* указываете?

Comment: в качестве логина указываю имя заданное через Мастер конфигурации защиты

Comment: *Мастер Здравого Смысла* подсказывает мне, что раз вы указали использовать учётные записи из *Локальной Операционной Системы*, то так и следует поступить: использовать имя пользователя, чей пароль вам известен, и этот самый пароль.

Comment: Ну видимо мастер здравого смысла проигрывает, потому что все равно пишет, что либо идентификатор, либо пароль не верен

Comment: вероятно, можно наконец-то воспользоваться *Мастером Чтения Документации*.

Comment: Ну вот не помогло, прочитал только, что ничего не сработает, если не сгенерить /etc/shadow/, но не помогло

Comment: я бы не стал рисковать запускать программу, в документации к которой написано, что «надо сгенерить /etc/shadow».

Comment: @tututu вы про это? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server